# How to update component Status at Form create?

Tags: delphi, components

I had created a simple program which includes many checkboxes and `TComboEdit`. When an certain checkbox is checked, then an editbox becomes enabled. 
Some checkbox is checked by default. My problem is when I run the program the unchecked component's edit box are visible too, which should be disabled as the checkbox is not checked at all.
 But when I check them and uncheck again the edit box disables which it should be. 
So how to update component's status at form create ? Or any other good way to do it.

so sorry for the grammar mistakes.

Comment: You need to initialize the state somehow.  How you do this depends on things we cannot possibly know about your program.  Either do it at design time or at runtime, but you have to do it somewhere.  Your components' interaction event handlers will naturally not execute during startup.

Comment: Perhaps you need to write an `OnCreate` event handler. There's only so far that you can go as a programmer using only the mouse. Eventually you have to write some code.

Answer (score 1):

Either set the visible property of the edit fields to false in the designer, or do as David Heffernan suggests: Write an OnCreate handler, where you do that in code.

Comment: thanks for answer. i don't want to disable the edit box at design time i want to disable them at form create or i want them to get disabled automatically at form create by getting the checkbox's status whether they are checked or not. i can disable them at design time but problem is that i have many version inside that program so in first version that checkbox and edit box both are visible but in some version both are not enabled and visible. so i just want to update the status and other component react as per status of checkbox's. i you got.